# Mitigating Docker Compliance Issues - Can I put everything in the `daemon.json`?

Tags: docker, security, devsecops

I am going through compliance tasks to harden our Docker setup and I am seeing many things like

- Favor using `docker run` with `docker run --pids-limit 100` to prevent forkbombs
- Favor using `docker run` with `docker run --security-opt=no-new-privileges` to be safe

etc...

I want to know if I can apply these settings across the board by, say, putting

```
...
"pids-limit": "100",
"security-opt": "no-new-privileges",
...
```

in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

I prefer to just have a hardened config on all my machines I am hardening.

Tips and tricks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [dockerd options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).  This will apply to all containers managed by the Docker Daemon.

Docker also has quite a bit of documentation on how to enforce different standards and compliance [here](https://docs.docker.com/compliance/).